# SQL Server 2008 erorr install dbenggine "is not a valid login or you don't have permission"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got an error trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express. In the middle of the installation, this error occurred:

> is not a valid login or you don't have permission

I googled that problem is my computer name is same with username, I don't know what username mean? Username `sqlserver` or what?

Comment: let me guess... maybe your computer name and login name are the same?

Comment: solved i change to workgroup from domain

Answer (score 0):

In case computer name same with login user's name, do change the login user's name. Then the issue will solved.